# Amateur trying a quiz-like batch file game. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: batch-file

This is the basis of my quiz game I was trying to make in the form of a batch file. I'm very new, so me doing something wrong is not that unlikely. What I want is for it to go to the proper area and in this demo go back to the start, however in the final version go to the next question. What currently happens is it just goes to the first subroutine rather than the specified one.
Thank you in advanced

```
@ECHO OFF
:start
echo Will you say yes or no?
set /p dummy=Say yes or no...
if "%INPUT%"=="yes" goto yes
if "%input%"=="no" goto no
if not "%input%"=="yes" goto lol
if not "%input%"=="no" goto lol
:yes
echo this worked
pause
echo Time for a repeat
pause
goto start
:no
echo this still worked
pause
echo Time for a repeat
pause
goto start
:lol
echo You did not put in yes or no. Try again
goto start
```

Comment: Please post what output you are currently getting and what you expected

Answer (score 0):

`input` is the variable name you use afterwards, so try

```
set /p input=Say yes or no...
```

instead of `dummy`.
And then:

```
if not "%input%"=="yes" goto lol
if not "%input%"=="no" goto lol
```

since you have caught 'yes' before, `not "%input%"=="yes"` is always true here. The next line can never be reached. And at the moment, you can replace both lines simply with `goto lol` if it is supposed to handle 'all the rest'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@ECHO OFF
:start
echo Will you say yes or no?
set /p input=Say yes or no...
if "%input%"=="yes" goto yes
if "%input%"=="no" goto no
if not "%input%"=="yes" goto lol
if not "%input%"=="no" goto lol
:yes
echo this worked
pause
echo Time for a repeat
pause
goto start
:no
echo this still worked
pause
echo Time for a repeat
pause
goto start
:lol
echo You did not put in yes or no. Try again
goto start
```

hope this works